# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent column name conflict

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have the following method in my `user` class:

```
/**
 * Get all organisations for user (if owner)
 *
 * @param
 */
public function getOrganisationsOwned()
{
    // If the user is owner of any one or many organisations then return this list
    return Organisation::leftJoin('subscription_plans', 'organisations.subscription_plan_id', '=', 'subscription_plans.id')
        ->where('organisations.owner_id', '=', $this->id)
        ->select('organisations.*', 'subscription_plans.*')
        ->get();

}
```

The method essentially queries and joins two tables. Each table has a column called `title`.

The output from the above generates the rows as desired with the right info, but returns only one `title` column, from the right table (`subscription_plans`) but not the column `title` from the left table (`organisations`). I also notice it is dropping the timestamps from one table also, as these are of the same column name.

I understood that

`->select('organisations.*', 'subscription_plans.*')`

would make the query return both columns. What am I missing? Happy new year!

PS: below is a copy of the `dd()` contents for the collection, with `title` only appearing once.

```
  #attributes: array:44 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "title" => "Monthly Subscription"
    "address_1" => "34 Florence Street"
    "address_2" => ""
    "suburb" => "Hornsby"
    "state" => "NSW"
    "postcode" => "2077"
    "country_id" => 12
    "currency_id" => 12
    "time_zone_id" => 109
    "phone" => "0392144497"
    "website" => "http://www.Tremblay.com/est-aspernatur-et-ut-provident.html"
    "business_id" => "82297955560"
    "tax_registration" => 1
    "logo" => "8aa656de-2bc2-4e14-dddd-e02fbcd2b76f"
    "quote_terms_days" => 14
    "invoice_terms_days" => 14
    "fiscal_start_id" => 7
    "industry_id" => 4
    "company_size_id" => 3
    "date_format_id" => 2
    "date_time_format_id" => 20
    "owner_id" => 1
    "gateway_id" => "1"
    "gateway_username" => "xxx"
    "gateway_password" => "xxx"
    "gateway_signature" => "xxx"
    "gateway_accepted_cards" => "[1, 2, 3]"
    "subscription_plan_id" => 1
    "trial_ends_at" => "2015-11-07"
    "grace_ends_at" => "2016-02-10"
    "subscription_ends_at" => "2016-01-11"
    "latitude" => "-33.70433500"
    "longitude" => "151.10161900"
    "registration" => "done"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "created_at" => "2016-01-01 14:59:47"
    "updated_at" => "2016-01-01 14:59:47"
    "amount" => "9.09"
    "gst" => "0.91"
    "gst_amount" => "10.00"
    "billing_cycle" => "MONTH"
    "trial_period_days" => 30
    "grace_period_days" => 30
  ]
```

The "missing" `title` column contains:

```
'title' => 'ABC Electrical'
```

Comment: How do you know that the query does not return both columns? How did you try to retrieve the 2 columns?

Comment: I do a `dd()` and inspect the collection contents. the column title only appears once. How I select the columns is in the query above.

Comment: My guess is that the query retrieves both title columns (get the sql string and paste it into your favourite mysql management app and execute it), but when the results are converted to a php array somewhere, the same name causes the remapping of the 2 columns to the same key, thus the value from the right table overrides the value from the left table. I would use var_dump() on the results to see what has been really retrieved. Instead of using *, you could list the field names one by one and provide aliases for the 2 title fields.

Comment: Hi @Shadow, thanks. Your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 1):

There is some misunderstanding as to what I suggested: instead of using *, you could list the field names one by one and provide aliases for the 2 title fields. This does not mean that you should keep the `'organisations.*', 'subscription_plans.*'` and add the 2 title fields to the select list with aliases because this way you select both title fields twice, wasting memory and processor time.

You should not include the * forms in the select list, but list each field individually, with the 2 title fields marked with aliases:

```
public function getOrganisationsOwned()
{
    // If the user is owner of any one or many organisations then return this list
    return Organisation::leftJoin('subscription_plans', 'organisations.subscription_plan_id', '=', 'subscription_plans.id')
        ->where('organisations.owner_id', '=', $this->id)
        ->select('organisations.id', 'organisations.title AS org_title', ..., 'subscription_plans.subscription_plan_id', 'subscription_plans.title AS plan_title', ...)
        ->get();
}
```

Yeah, I know, listing so many field one by one is a pain in the ***, however, each field is retrieved once and only once, at it is clear that you are fetching what is needed.

Comment: Hi @Shadow, got it, but there are a lot of fields to list. In SQL the `TableA.*`, `TableB.*` works, so I still do not understand why it is not working in this case.

Comment: @TheRealPapa I did a little research on google and came up with the following topic on laravel's issues log: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2333 apparently this is a result of a deliberate design decision in laravel.

Comment: @TheRealPapa however, I find it a bit ridiculous that in order to save about 5 mins on coding time, you are willing to retrieve 2 fields twice to work around 'dedign feature' in your chosen ORM...

Comment: Ok got it. I thought your suggestion was workaround but it seems it is the only way. I am not wanting to list cols as I am adding / deleting cols as I complete the design and did not want to have to update code all over the place

Answer (score 0):

@Shadow's suggestion worked, although you should note, this method allows you to select all the fields, but only "rename" columns or rather alias them so you can still access the proper value when using joins. The old value will still be overridden, but now you can use your alias with the correct value.

The below is now working:

```
public function getOrganisationsOwned()
{
    // If the user is owner of any one or many organisations then return this list
    return Organisation::leftJoin('subscription_plans', 'organisations.subscription_plan_id', '=', 'subscription_plans.id')
        ->where('organisations.owner_id', '=', $this->id)
        ->select('organisations.*', 'organisations.title AS org_title', 'subscription_plans.*', 'subscription_plans.title AS plan_title')
        ->get();
}
```

Comment: This comment is an automatic message from the review queue. This answer comes in the Low Quality Posts review queue because someone flagged it as LQ. As your answer is a comment on Shadow answer (which should be accepted as it answer  the problem **initially** stated in your question) it should have been writen in a comment on his post. And I'm not bored at all in life, thanks.